# UITextField trouble

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

okay i have no idea whats going on. im relatively new to iOS so my debugging skills are not where they need to be. i have a text field that was working just fine until i did some changes in my app, changes that didnt have anything to do with the text field (at least i thought they didnt). i keep getting this error "-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1a1803490" after i try to type. right after the debug area prints "did begin editing". any help is appreciated. thanks in advance.

here is my code:

```
 @IBAction func textFieldActions(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("text field actions")
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    textField.becomeFirstResponder()
    print("did begin editing")
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    print("did end ediditing")
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    textField.text = nil

    return true

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok basically the error you get means you are trying to call some method on an object that doesn't have such method. 
Here the object is actually null, so you are trying to call a method on something null. You are maybe nilling your textfield somewhere in your code?

The code you have gave here is fine, so it's not coming from this, what didn't change before it broke the code?

Also, we need to find where that error happens. To do so, **create an exception breakpoint**, so that Xcode will point out the exact line where the crash occurs :

> Debug>Breakpoints>Create exception breakpoint...>ok

Comment: i did that, but nothing is different in the debug area.

Answer (score 0):

may be debug area has more information. please capture entire list for helpers. and u don't neccessary use responder functions. It already done.
I doubt you setting text of textfield from dictionary having NSNull value.
NSNull is somekind of nil object for that shouldn't have nil value in container.

Answer (score 0):

OP here. i fixed the issue. no idea why or how, but a way to fix this is removing any tabbar controllers or navigation controllers from your storyboard scene and putting them back in.